# No password screen lock option -- Can it be enabled?

Tags: lock-screens, password

I'm using a PALM phone which for whatever reason has no Password screen lock option.  Only swipe and PIN options.

Does anyone know of a way to get the password option enabled that you typically have with most android phones?

Thanks!

Comment: guess that's intentionally because of the keyboard size

Comment: @alecxs yes it seems to be true it must be intentional.  Thing you can use the keybaord for everyhting else, why not for lock screen.  I guess a case of trying to make things userfriendly which turns into a fail for some people.  :)